# proof question: Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space, and let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space, and let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be linear.

a). if $\mathrm{rank} (T)= \mathrm{rank} (T^2)$, prove $R(T) \bigcap N(T)$={0}.

$N(T)$ is defined by $T(0_V)=0_W$ for any finite dimensional $T: V\rightarrow W$.

Since $V$ is finite-dimensional vector space, from dimensional theorem,
$$\dim(V)=\dim(N(T)+\dim(R(T))-\dim(N(T) \cap R(T))$$

How can I go further ahead and deduce that $R(T) \bigcap N(T)$={0}?

Comment: No, you cannot conclude that $T$ "is an identity map". For example, the map $T\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $T(x,y) = (x,0)$ satisfies $\mathrm{rank}(T)=\mathrm{rank}(T^2)$ (both are equal to $1$), but $T$ is not "an identity map" (nor is it injective, even).

Comment: R(T) is the rank of T. How come it doesn't define N(T) then? I thought that was from the definition.

Comment: Rank is a natural number: the dimension of the column (row) space of the matrix of $T$, it is not a set.

Comment: My guess is $N(T)$ is the kernel and $R(T)$ the image.

Comment: @Beacon: The rank *does* define the nullity (in terms of $\dim(V)$) but it doesn't prove it is equal to $0$, which is your assertion. Note that $R(T)$ is the range, $N(T)$ is the nullspace, $\mathrm{rank}(T)$ is the rank, $\mathrm{nullity}(T)$ or $\mathrm{null}(T)$ is the nullity. Don't confuse the rank with the range, or the nullspace with the nullity. Knowing the range tells you the dimension of the nullspace, but it doesn't tell you the nullspace.

Comment: Hint: Show that $R(T^2) = T(R(T))$. What happens if $N(T)\cap R(T)$ is not the zero subspace?

Comment: You are misquoting the Dimension Theorem. The Dimension Theorem just says that $\dim(V) = \dim(\mathrm{rank}(T)) + \dim{\mathrm{N}(T)}$. There is no term with the intersection.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  thought there is a Gaussman formula that includes the intersection of Rank T and  N(T)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin i will be careful with the notion. Thx!

Comment: Please, if you find a flaw in my solution, discuss it with me, i'm learning LA myself, that would be educative.

Comment: @Beacon: It don’t think you are correct. I think that you are confusing the formula $\dim(A+B)=\dim(A)+\dim(B)-\dim(A\cap B)$ with the dimension theorem.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yeah I really did mix two things together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T:V \to V$ is a linear map. Now when you're considering $T^2=T \circ T$ , note that $\tilde{T} =T|_{R(T)} :R(T) \to R(T)$ is basically an isomorphism by Rank-nullity theorem since, $Rank(T)=Rank(T^2)$ .

Let, $v \in R(T) \cap N(T)$ , then $T(v)=0$ and $\exists w \in V$ such that $Tw=v$ . Thus $T^2w=Tv=0 \implies \tilde{T}(Tw)=0\implies \tilde{T}v=0$ . As we showed earlier that $\tilde{T}$ is an isomorphism on $R(T)$ it follows that $\tilde{T}v=0 \implies v=0$

Hence, $R(T) \cap N(T)=\{0\}$

Answer (score 1):

We know from rank-nullity theorem that $\text{rank}(T)+\text{nulity}(T)=\text{dim}(V)$ ($N(T)$ is the null-space of $T$ and $R(T)$ is the image of $T$, $V$ is domain and co-domain, both). Assume $\text{rank}(T) =r$, $\text{nulity}(T)=n$ and $\text{dim}(V)=v$.
Let's $\{ x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_r,x_{r+1}\cdots,x_v \}$ be a complete basis for $V$, thus any relation $\sum_{i=1}^{m}c_ix_i=0$ indicates $\forall i: c_i=0$ (where $1\le m\le v$);This basis has the property that $\{x_{r+1},\cdots ,x_v\}$ forms a basis for null space of $T$ (in other words we expanded the basis of null space of $T$ to get a complete basis for $V$). Thus $\forall i, r+1 \le i \le v: T(x_i)=0$. The image of $T$ , i.e. $y_i=T(x_i) , i=1,\cdots , r$ can be written in this basis as $\forall i: y_i = \sum_{j=1}^{v}d_{ij}x_j$.

Finally considering $z\in R(T)\cap N(T)$, we can write $z = \sum_{k=1}^{r}f_ky_k(\in R(T))=\sum_{l=r+1}^{v}e_lx_l(\in N(T))$. Applying $T$ on $z$ gives $T(z)=\sum_{l=r+1}^{v}e_lT(x_l)=0$, but we know that $z=\sum_{k=1}^{r}f_ky_k= \sum_{k=1}^{r}f_k\left(\sum_{j=1}^{v}d_{kj}x_j\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{v}g_jx_j$. Applying $T$ on $z$ now gives

$$T(z)=\sum_{j=1}^{v}g_jT(x_j)=\sum_{j=1}^{r}g_jT(x_j)=T\left(\sum_{j=1}^{r}g_jx_j\right)=0$$

Considering the fact that $T\left(\sum_{j=1}^{r}g_jx_j\right)=0$ and $\forall i, i=r+1,\cdots ,v:T(T(x_i))=T(0)=0$ means $\text{nullity}(T^2)>\text{nullity}(T)$ and thus $\text{rank}(T^2)<\text{rank}(T)$ which is a contradiction unless $\forall i, 1\le i \le r: g_i=0$ implying $z\in N(T)$ and $z\notin R(T)$, but that also contradicts with $z\in R(T)\cap N(T)$. Therefore our only option is $z=0$.